# List understanding python

Tags: python, list, math

I'm pretty confused i'm supposed to take a file that the user inputs and take the scores in the text document and turn it into a list.

the problem I'm having is that when i turn it into a list it gives me three separate list under one variable.

```
def main():
    file = input("Enter a filename: ")
    file1 = open(file, "r")
    Scores = (file1.readlines())
    for line in Scores:
        scores = [eval(i) for i in line.split()]

        print(scores)
```

and i get this as an output:

```
[34, 34, 54, 14, 32, 24, 31, 34, 53, 74, 22, 29]
[54, 34, 14, 14, 32, 24, 31, 34, 53, 74, 22, 29]
[66, 53, 19, 45, 39, 72, 51, 46, 64, 33, 44, 55]
```

could i please get help turning this into one whole list so i can display how many scores there are, the total of all of them, and the average.

Comment: 1. Why are you using `eval` (not e.g. `int`)? 2. Where is your attempt to put them into a single list?

Comment: my attempt is the: for line in scores. It just gives me 3 list and i dont know the names of them to be able to add them together

Comment: What do you mean *"know the names of them"*?!

Comment: Thanks to those that help. @jonrsharpe all i wanted was help and apparently others understood what i meant and saw that i attempted so please don't comment if your intent is not to help and  to criticize

Comment: @user6263406 If one of the answers solves your problem, please mark it as *Accepted* by clicking the checkmark under its vote arrows.

Comment: I would also suggest that it would help you to learn some of the usual programming terminology - "knowing the name of them" doesn't have a well defined meaning, whereas, say, "what variable they are" is well defined, and most users here will understand what you want.  Consider: if you're reading in scores, could each score not have the name of the person who got it?  The majority of programmers like language to be precise - like the coding language we use every day.  It isn't meant as criticism, just an attempt to figure out what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
def main():
    file = input("Enter a filename: ")
    file1 = open(file, "r")
    Scores = (file1.readlines())
    scores_list = []
    for line in Scores:
        scores_list.extend([eval(i) for i in line.split()])

    print(scores_list)
```

The trick is to `extend` an existing list with your new list for each line in the file.

Note that there are other opportunities for improvements here... e.g. you could use a context manager to manage closing the file properly:

```
 def main():
    filename = input("Enter a filename: ")
    scores_list = []
    with open(filename, "r") as file1:
        for line in file1:
            scores_list.extend([eval(i) for i in line.split()])

    print(scores_list)
```

Finally (and probably most importantly), you can probably just swap out your use of `eval` for `int` or `float` (depending on the inputs) and make your program much more secure.  As it is, `eval` will run any untrusted code on your machine.  To demonstrate, add a line with `exit()` into your text file and notice that your program exits before it does *anything*.  An attacker could use this to do malicious things (like wipe your home-directory or even your entire drive if the script runs with high enough permissions).

Comment: FWIW, you can also drop the `[]` in the `.extend`:  `scores_list.extend(int(i) for i in line.split())`.

Comment: You should probably extend on what you mean by "more secure"... A score of `exit()` would be a good example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension for this as one way

```
file = input("Enter a filename: ")
with open(file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    scores = [int(i) for line in lines for i in line.split()]
    print(scores)
```

Comment: It seems like OP wants to split on whitespace, not `','`